# Switch Ramps 1.4 z/x axis

Tags: arduino

I've got an arduino mega 2560 with ramps 1.4 and I want to use 2 motors on the x or y axis rather than the z axis.  What's the easiest way to do this?  There's 2 open spots for the z motors but only one for the x and y.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest method would be to just use the dual Z motor sockets for another axis, IF you have control over the Gcode you'll be running.  You could swap all X and Z positions and moves.

According to the wiki [RepRap wiki](http://reprap.org/wiki/RAMPS_1.4) there are five sockets.  You could just hook up one Z motor and hook the extra motor up to the Extruder 2 socket.  But either way you'll need to recompile and re-flash the firmware to mirror (X axis, for example) signals to the extra socket.

If you, as I am, are making a router and not a printer, then you could alternatively try the grbl firmware instead.  You still have to flash the Arduino, but the port mapping with grbl is very straightforward, just a header file change.  You should examine 'cpu_map.h' for the pin/port assignments and you should also set up 'defaults.h' something like this:

```
#define DEFAULT_STEP_PULSE_MICROSECONDS 20
#define MICROSTEPS 1

#define STEPS_PER_REV 200.0
#define MM_PER_REV ((1.0/20.0)*MM_PER_INCH) //  leadscrew 1/4" x 20 leadscrew
#define DEFAULT_X_STEPS_PER_MM (STEPS_PER_REV*MICROSTEPS/MM_PER_REV)
#define DEFAULT_Y_STEPS_PER_MM (STEPS_PER_REV*MICROSTEPS/MM_PER_REV)
#define DEFAULT_Z_STEPS_PER_MM (STEPS_PER_REV*MICROSTEPS/MM_PER_REV)
#define DEFAULT_X_MAX_RATE 500//635.0 // mm/min (25 ipm)
#define DEFAULT_Y_MAX_RATE 500//635.0 // mm/min
#define DEFAULT_Z_MAX_RATE 500 //635.0 // mm/min
```

Be careful, make good backups or check your code into a revision control system, something.  I run grbl using bCNC [bCNC](https://github.com/vlachoudis/bCNC) on a Raspberry Pi 3 using a "shield" I designed to plug into the end pin header on the Arduino 2560.  My homemade "shield" simply has the outputs as I want them, you can make one out of .1" protoboard, it's not hard.

Comment: Thanks!  It's a laser engraver.  I'll try grbl.

Comment: Do you know what file I need to edit for the port changes?

Comment: It's possible to get list of variables of change ?

Answer (score 0):

For Marlin branch bugfix-2.0.x, patch the following to swap Y and Z axis for RAMPS 1.4 in Marlin/src/pins/ramps/pins_RAMPS.h.

```
*** pins_RAMPS.h    2020-01-30 19:15:27.589769115 +0800
--- pins_RAMPS.h.bak    2020-01-30 19:14:22.269122126 +0800
***************
*** 126,143 ****
    #define X_CS_PIN         53
  #endif

! #define Z_STEP_PIN         60
! #define Z_DIR_PIN          61
! #define Z_ENABLE_PIN       56
! #ifndef Z_CS_PIN
!   #define Z_CS_PIN         49
  #endif

! #define Y_STEP_PIN         46
! #define Y_DIR_PIN          48
! #define Y_ENABLE_PIN       62
! #ifndef Y_CS_PIN
!   #define Y_CS_PIN         40
  #endif

  #define E0_STEP_PIN        26
--- 126,143 ----
    #define X_CS_PIN         53
  #endif

! #define Y_STEP_PIN         60
! #define Y_DIR_PIN          61
! #define Y_ENABLE_PIN       56
! #ifndef Y_CS_PIN
!   #define Y_CS_PIN         49
  #endif

! #define Z_STEP_PIN         46
! #define Z_DIR_PIN          48
! #define Z_ENABLE_PIN       62
! #ifndef Z_CS_PIN
!   #define Z_CS_PIN         40
  #endif

  #define E0_STEP_PIN        26
```